# Load HTML Snippets into DOM

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to come up with the best way to maintain a site with lots of pages, and I've opted to create separate HTML files for "common" HTML elements like the header and footer.

Currently, my **index.html** page is set up like this, where the jQuery function is supposed to inject the contents of `text.html` into the footer div.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Site</title>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $("#footer").load("text.html");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The contents of **text.html** are:

```
<div style="red">
    Hello, world!
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to work and i am getting following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/Jon/Desktop/text.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

**Question:** Is this possible via jQuery, or do I have to use PHP/something else? I know that Wordpress does something similar, but I'm pretty sure they use PHP. This method will be very sustainable if I can get it to work.

Comment: There is no need any server side language like PHP to do this. Do you have any error in console?

Comment: what error are you getting ? try `$("#footer").load("text.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "error") {
var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
$("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
}`

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/Jon/Desktop/text.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: update your question with this error message. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load file:// URLs in most browsers via AJAX requests or you will get `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`  I believe Firefox will let you, but Chrome/Safari don't.  ( See [Google Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files disabled for Chrome Beta 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270999/google-chrome-allow-file-access-from-files-disabled-for-chrome-beta-8) for more)

The easiest thing is to run a local webserver, then you won't get that error.

Also, in terms of what you are doing, there are much nicer libraries to do this than jQuery.  I'm using https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Reusable-UI-Dust-modules - which is similar to [How to define mustache partials in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076817/how-to-define-mustache-partials-in-html) - both have partials/includes of other files.  You could also look at http://pagerjs.com/

One other project worth checking out is http://docpad.org/ - which will also install a webserver for you.  Once you are finished working on a site, you can generate static HTML from all the parts.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need server-side language

in replay to your error message described in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057390/regular-expression-for-alpha-numeric-space-dash-and-hash)

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/Jon/Desktop/text.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

you need a native web server setup, and running it by calling your localhost or 127.0.0.1

---

**Good Read**

[**Jquery: Running AJAX locally without a webserver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397644/jquery-running-ajax-locally-without-a-webserver)