# Regular Expression for alpha numeric, space, dash, and hash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm still a newbie for regular expressions. I want to create a regular expression with this rule:

```
if (preg_match('^[ A-Za-z0-9_-#]^', $text) == 1) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

In short, I would like $text to accept texts, numbers, spaces, underscores, dashes, and hashes (#).
Is the above reg expression correct? it always return true.

Comment: You have two `^` anchors.

Comment: @Orangepill Nope, the dash is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't use `^` as the expression boundaries, because they're also used for  expression anchors; use `/`, `~` or `#` instead.

Second, the dash in the character set should be at the last position; otherwise it matches the range from `_` until `#`, and that's probably not what you want.

Third, the expression now only matches a single character; you will want to use a multiplier such as `+` or `*`.

Lastly, you should anchor the expression so that only those valid characters are present in the string:

```
/^[ \w#-]+$/
```

Btw, I've replaced `A-Za-z0-9_` with `\w` as a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

That you can do:

1. `\w` stand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
2. the character `-` have a special meaning in a character class since it is used to define ranges, thus you must place it at the begining or at the end of the class
3. the preg_match function return 0 if there is no match or false when an error occurs, thus you don't need to test if it is equal to 1 (you can use that preg_match returns to do things)

example:

```
if (preg_match('~[\w #-]++~', $subject))
     ...
else
     ...
```